# Change other select box options on one select box change- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing security questions for my project during login.

For Example, I have 4 questions and 4 `<select>` boxes to select each question

1. What is your father's middle name?
2. What is the first name of your first manager?
3. In what city was your father born?
4. What is the name of your pet?

Initially all the `<select>` boxes are populated all 4 questions

Now if the user selects 1st question from 1st `<select>` box, this question should be omitted/hidden from other `<select>` boxes i.e the remaining questions (other than 1st) should be available for 2nd `<select>` box

Also if I go back to my 1st select box and change the question, the `<option>` changes should be reflected in other text `<select>` box

Now I obviously have more than 4 questions in my project to make sure that user is not left without any options for the last `<select>`.

**[This is what I have tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/shstrhbb/)**. But it creates undesirable results

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider all select boxes when checking for selected values, I've added one more loop using .each as follows:

```
var questions = 
[
    {
        "text" : "What is your father's middle name?",
        "value" : "1"
    },
    {
        "text" : "What is the first name of your first manager?",
        "value" : "2"
    },
    {
        "text" : "In what city was your father born?",
        "value" : "3"
    },
    {
        "text" : "What is the name of your pet?",
        "value" : "4"
    }

];
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('select').each(function(){
        var selectbox = $(this).empty();
            for(var i = 0, l = questions.length; i < l; i++){
            var question = questions[i];
                selectbox.append($('<option>', { 
                    value: question.value,
                    text : question.text 
                }));
            }
        });

        $('select').change(function(){
        var selectid = this.id;
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('select').each(function(){
            var seleid = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#"+seleid+" > option").each(function(){
                if(seleid !== selectid)
                {
        sel = $(this);
        $("#"+seleid+" option[value="+this.value+"]").show();
        $('select').each(function(){
           sel.value === value
           $("#"+seleid+" option[value="+this.value+"]").hide();    
        });                                         
                }
            });
        });


    })

    });
```

**See demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/0vu7snhx/

Answer (score 0):

Try This Hope it will work.

```
'$("#select1").change(function() {
      if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
           $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
       }
       var id = $(this).val();
       var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
       $('#select2').html(options);
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>'



<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="1">Banana</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="1">Orange</option>
  <option value="2">Wolf</option>
  <option value="2">Fox</option>
  <option value="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="3">Eagle</option>
  <option value="3">Hawk</option>
  <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<select id='one'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<select id='two'>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#one').change(function(){
    var op= "<option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option>";
    $('#two').html(op);
  });
});
```